# JavaFX Multithreading Issue

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm currently making an application in which we want to use multithreading to display the flashing label "loading" for a certain period of time after logging in, before continuing on to the next page. Here is my current progress:

```
public class LoadingController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label loadingLabel;

boolean ready = false;

public void setReady() {
    System.out.println("now I'm ready");
    ready = true;
}

public void showLabel() {
    this.loadingLabel.setVisible(true);
}

public void hideLabel() {
    this.loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
}

public void goToPage2() {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Page2.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = Assignment.getStage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoadingController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    System.out.println("In loading page");
    // TODO launch thread
    Thread2 thread = new Thread2(this);
    thread.start();


}
```

}

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {

private LoadingController con;

public Thread2(LoadingController con) {
    this.con = con;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            con.hideLabel();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            con.showLabel();
            Thread.sleep(100);

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    con.setReady();

}
```

}

I currently get this error relating to line 
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread.

Would anyone be able to provide some guidance on this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The guidance is very simple - read the relevant documentation about JavaFX concurrency.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

The exception clearly tells you what is wrong. You try to create a new Scene from the wrong thread. SceneGraph manipulations are only allowed from the JavaFX application thread.